# iOS 7, table header view does not float

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` set up on my app, which runs on iOS 7. I has one section and it loads images into custom cells and it scrolls under the `navigation bar` as well, which is translucent. So initially, the content is below the `navbar` and it scrolls under the `navbar` as we scroll down to view more images. For this I have set an initial `contentInset` of `UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 0, 0)`. Now sometimes, I need a small header view on my table to indicate types of images on my table. So I have used the following code:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 30.0;

}

-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    TableSectionHeader *header=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableSectionHeader" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    [header.title setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Type: %@", self.imageType]];

    return head;
}
```

Where `TableSectionHeader` is custom view I have created for this purpose. Now ideally, the header must float or "stick" either just below the `navbar` or at the top of the table (which is under the navbar). But in this case, it just rolls off screen. I want the header to stick right under the `navbar`. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change the table view's style from `Grouped` to `Plain`.

From the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/tableviewstyles/tableviewcharacteristics.html), regarding the `Plain` table view style:

> A plain table view can have one or more sections, sections can have
>   one or more rows, and each section can have its own header or footer
>   title. (A header or footer may also have a custom view, for instance
>   one containing an image). **When the user scrolls through a section with
>   many rows, the header of the section floats to the top of the table
>   view and the footer of the section floats to the bottom.**