# How can I make my header sticky to tableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I create header with

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and set it height with

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I have one header and one section.

I create VC in code inherited from UITableViewController
I use UITableViewStyleGrouped

but then I scroll down header is disappear

Comment: you can check the same answer from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582818/uitableview-with-fixed-section-headers/50814836#50814836

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Plain tableViewStyle. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555068/ios-7-table-header-view-does-not-float)

```
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```